# Performance problems and optimizations for csv file to SQL Routes

Tags: apache-camel

pretty new to Camel, but good fun so far.

I am using it to process csv files that are FTP:d to a particular directory,  parse them and then place the data in relevant MySql db tables (all on the same host).

I have a simple CamelContext containing 4 routes, each of which process a different file type and place the parsed data in its associated table. A number of these files can appear in the FTP directory every 15 minutes (on the clock 15, 30 45, 00 minutes).

The camel context registry has only one entry, that of the dataSource (a simple Mysql datasource provided by org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource...we are migrating over to MaraiDb)

Each of the 4 routes follow the pattern below,differing only in the "from file" name pattern, and the choice of Processor:

```
from("file:" + FilePath + "?include=(.*)dmm_all(.*)csv.gz&" + fileAction + "&moveFailed=" + FaultyFilePath)
                        .routeId("myRoute")
                        .unmarshal().gzip()
                        .unmarshal().csv()
                        .split().body()
                        .process(myProcessor)
                        .choice()
                        .when(simple("${header.myResult} != 'header removed'"))
                        .to("sql:" + insertQuery.trim() + "?dataSource=sqlds")
                        .end();
```

Each Processor just removes the file header (column names) and sets the body for insert into the associated MySql table with the given insert query.

For incoming files it works like a charm.

But when the application/Camel process is not up, the FTP directory can fill up with a lot of files. 
Starting the application in this situation is when the performance problems arise.

I get the following exception(s) with a certain file ammount threshold:

```
Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
Could not get JDBC Connection; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
Could not connect to localhost:3306 : Cannot assign requested address
```

I have tried adding a delay on each route, and it goes smoothly, but painfully slow.

I am guessing (wildly..I might add) that there is contention between the route threads (if that is how camel works with a thread for each route?) and the single db connection for the dataSource.

Is this the case, if whats the best strategy to solve this (connection pool? or using a single shared thread for all the routes or...)?

What other strategies are there to improve performance in the Camel scenario I use above?

Very grateful for any input and feedback.

cheers.

Comment: yeah sounds like you need connection pooling for the JDBC so you can do concurrent access to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Good to know I wasn't far wrong in my analysis.